# Selecting strings and case sensitivity

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter for an object that has a *Title* field, and I want to ignore case.  Is there a way to make sure case sensitivity if turned off?

```
| Where-Object {$_.Title -like "myString"}
```

Comment: Related post - [Powershell case sensitivity variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38171569/465053)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

PowerShell is fundamentally case insensitive (e.g. `"HEy" -like "hey"` is `True`).

If you want to use the case sensitive version of `like`, use `-clike`.

Comment: It is so case insensitive that the following returns true : 

"foo" -like "Foo" returns True

but 

"foo" -eq "FoO" returns True - not what I expected.

Answer (score 49):

By default case sensitivity is off:

```
PS> 'test','TEST','TeSt','notest' | ? { $_ -like 'test' }
test
TEST
TeSt
```

From documentation:

> By default, all comparison operators
>   are case-insensitive. To make a
>   comparison operator case-sensitive,
>   precede the operator name with a `"c"`.
>   For example, the case-sensitive
>   version of `"-eq"` is `"-ceq"`. To make
>   the case-insensitivity explicit,
>   precede the operator with an `"i"`. For
>   example, the explicitly
>   case-insensitive version of `"-eq"` is
>   `"-ieq"`.

For more information run `help about_comparison_operators`

Answer (score 2):

A more generic approach, I think, would be to use regular expressions, which is especially handy for people who has learned regular expressions from another language such as Perl. Example:

```
'test','TEST','TeSt','notest' | ? { $_ -match '(?-i)^test' }
test
```

Comment: maybe more generic, but less idiomatic...

Comment: generic is objective, and idiomatic is subjective.