# PowerShell case sensitivity variables

Tags: powershell

I want to write a script that does a manipulation on users in my company.

Usernames can be with capital letters/small letters, and also the domain name is sometimes assigned to them with capital letters, so a username can be like:
domain\username, DOMAIN\USERNAME, DOMAIN\username or domain\USERNAME.

I ask for the username like this:

```
$user = Read-Host "Please insert username"
```

How can I make `$user` non case sensitive and also the company name?

The username needs to be like `$company\$user` without case sensitivity.

Comment: String don't care about the case of themselves. Operators and some methods would though. You would need to show us what you are doing with the variable for anyone to be able to answer this properly.

Comment: Are you currently running into issues? Not only will PowerShell often not car about case, but neither does Windows on a username by default.

Comment: _Case sensitivity_ concept has no sense without knowing _purpose_. For instance, all comparison operators are case-insensitive by default. Most windows `cmd` commands as well, e.g. `net user UsErNaMe` and `net user uSeRnAmE` are equivalent. Please [edit] your question and add your code satisfying [mcve] rules.

Answer (score 9):

String comparisons in PowerShell are typically case-insensitive by default.

Strings themselves are case *aware*, meaning they know that an `A` is a different glyph than an `a` and it will remember which was used, but the normal comparison operators (`-eq`, `-match`, `-like`, `-lt`, `-in`, etc.) are all case-insensitive.

You have to specify the case-sensitive versions for case-sensitive comparisons (`-ceq`, `-cmatch`, `-clike`, `-clt`, `-cin`, etc.).  You can also specify the explicitly case-insensitive operators (`-ieq`, `-imatch`, `-ilike`, `-ilt`, `-iin`, etc.).

If you want to force the characters to a specific case, you can do this:

```
#Set characters to lower case
$user = $user.ToLower();

#Set characters to upper case
$user = $user.ToUpper();
```

But there is no property of strings that marks them as inherently case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Special treatment is not needed, Windows credentials are case-insensitive so regardless of what case the user enters the domain or username you can pass that to a cmdlet or command line tool and it will just work.

For example, creating a PSCredential with the following usernames will have identical results:

- MyCompany\MyUsername
- mycompany\myusername
- MYCOMPANY\myusername
- MyCoMpAnY\mYuSeRnAmE

Additionally, by default PowerShell comparison operators are not case sensitive;

```
"CASE" -eq "case"    #returns true
"CASE" -ceq "case"   #case-sensitive version returns false
```

Comment: Re *"Windows credentials ... are naturally case-insensitive"*: I wouldn't call that blindingly obvious. Can you elaborate in your answer (e.g. I assume this may be for usernames, not passwords)? Or do you really mean case-insensitive? Or you mean it is PowerShell that is case-insensitive (but that may then lead to false positives or false negatives)?

Comment: Windows usernames are case-insensitive, PowerShell depends on what comparators you're using. The defaults eg `-eq` are case-insensitive, when required you have `-ceq` (case-equals), `-cin` (case-in), `clike` (case-like), etc for case-sensitive versions.